# root can't send mail (apticron) but user can (mail/mailx)

Tags: debian, email, root, mailx, ssmtp

- I'm running Debian
- I've set up `ssmtp` as my MTA and this works perfectly
- I can send mail using both `mail` and `mailx` with a standard user account

BUT... When I run `sudo apticron` I get:

```
send-mail: RCPT TO:<[user]@[mydomain].com> (550 Sender verify failed)
```

Any ideas? (I've blanked the email details myself - that's not part of the error)

---

UPDATE:

When running `mail` or `mailx` as root, these break too! They only work when I run them under my standard user account.

Error message I receive as root when running:

```
echo "test" | mail -s "test" [user]@[mydomain].com
```

is same as with apticron:

```
RCPT TO:[user]@[mydomain]> (550 Sender verify failed)
```

---

UPDATE 2:

`sudo mail -v etc...` shows that the root user actually replaces the first part of the email address with 'root' despite `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` specifying `FromLineOverride=NO`:

```
[<-] 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
[->] EHLO [user]@[mydomain].com
[<-] 250 HELP
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] [redacted Base64 username]
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 235 Authentication succeeded
[->] MAIL FROM:<root@[mydomain.com]>
[<-] 250 OK
[->] RCPT TO:<[user]@[mydomain].com>
[<-] 550 Sender verify failed
send-mail: RCPT TO:<[user]@[mydomain].com> (550 Sender verify failed)
```

---

EDIT:

I've removed previously pasted code from `apticron` as clearly the problem lies with root not being able to send emails (this is no longer limited to an individual program)

Comment: "sender verify" would sound like a problem with the *from* address. Not the recipient.

Comment: That's what I thought originally.. I've tried 4 different from addresses, all of which work perfectly with command line `mail` and `mailx`. Incidentally I think having a dash/hyphen in the from address breaks `ssmtp`, that's why I changed it originally.

Comment: @derobert I still haven't manage to resolve this. Any other advice? How can it be that I can send emails without any problem when I do `mail -s "something" my@emailaddress.com` but apticron fails every time if they're both using the same MTA?

Comment: Try a different MTA - exim is generally well supported on Debian, and see if that helps you figure it out.

Comment: If you get an error, post it, If you don't get an error, that might tell you something too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your remote mail server doesn't believe `root@yourdomain` in the SMTP envelope¹ is a valid email address, so it's refusing messages from you. And that's where apticron is trying to send from, so it doesn't work.

ssmtp allows you to override the default email address and relay on a per-user basis in the `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` file. You can use this to set an acceptable (to your mail relay) address for `root`, by adding a line like:

```
root:EMAIL@DOMAIN:RELAY-HOST:RELAY-PORT
```

replacing the all-caps portions with email address and relay host you'd like to use.

Note: Much of this was from troubleshooting in chat, starting around [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21199295#21199295).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the SMTP "envelope" sender is different than the From: field that shows up in your mail client. Though if you're lucky it's preserved in a different header.